# Heap selection sort - follow-up

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, heap

See the [previous and initial iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97958/heap-selection-sort-in-java).

I got rid of `Run` objects and just maintain two integer arrays in the `RunHeap`: one for starting indices, and another for ending indices. Also, thanks to a great suggestion by [@maaartinus](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/14363/maaartinus), the algorithm is now **stable**.

The last, but not least: I do not longer sift up a newly pushed run as soon it is added, but rather append it to the tail of the array, and once all runs are considered, I do a bulk `heapify`, which (according to Introduction to Algorithms) runs in \$\Theta(N)\$ time instead of \$\Theta(N \log N)\$, which is an improvement.

**HeapSelectionSort.java:**

```
package net.coderodde.util.sorting;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 * This class implements a sorting algorithm called 
 * <b><i>heap selection sort</i></b>. The worst case complexity is linearithmic
 * O(n log n), best case complexity linear O(n). Linear space complexity and is
 * now <b>stable</b>.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.61
 */
public class HeapSelectionSort {

    /**
     * Sorts the range {@code array[fromIndex], array[fromIndex + 1], ...,
     * array[toIndex - 2], array[toIndex - 1]} using the specified comparator.
     * 
     * @param <T>        the array component type.
     * @param array      the array holding the range to sort.
     * @param fromIndex  the starting (inclusive) index of the range to sort.
     * @param toIndex    the ending (exclusive) index of the range to sort.
     * @param comparator the array component comparator.
     */
    public static <T> void sort(T[] array, 
                                int fromIndex, 
                                int toIndex, 
                                Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        rangeCheck(array.length, fromIndex, toIndex);

        if (toIndex - fromIndex < 2) {
            return;
        }

        T[] aux = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, fromIndex, toIndex);
        RunHeap<T> heap = createRunHeap(aux, comparator);

        for (; fromIndex < toIndex; ++fromIndex) {
            array[fromIndex] = heap.popElement();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sorts the entire array using the specified comparator.
     * 
     * @param <T>        the array component type.
     * @param array      the array holding the range to sort.
     * @param comparator the array component comparator.
     */
    public static <T> void sort(T[] array, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        sort(array, 0, array.length, comparator);
    }

    /**
     * Sorts the range {@code array[fromIndex], array[fromIndex + 1], ...,
     * array[toIndex - 2], array[toIndex - 1]} using the natural comparator.
     * 
     * @param <T>        the array component type.
     * @param array      the array holding the range to sort.
     * @param fromIndex  the starting (inclusive) index of the range to sort.
     * @param toIndex    the ending (exclusive) index of the range to sort.
     */
    public static <T> void sort(T[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        sort(array, fromIndex, toIndex, NaturalOrder.INSTANCE);
    }

    /**
     * Sorts the entire array using the natural comparator.
     * 
     * @param <T>        the array component type.
     * @param array      the array holding the range to sort.
     */
    public static <T> void sort(T[] array) {
        sort(array, 0, array.length);
    }

    /**
     * Builds the actual run heap. A run is any contiguous subsequence that is
     * either ascending or (strictly) descending. We need descending runs to be
     * strictly descending because we will reverse them in order. Thus, if we
     * ever had contiguous equal elements, they would have been reversed and 
     * stability gone.
     * 
     * @param <T>        the array component type.
     * @param array      the actual array.
     * @param comparator the comparator.
     * @return the run heap.
     */
    private static <T> RunHeap<T> 
        createRunHeap(T[] array, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        RunHeap<T> heap = new RunHeap<>(array, comparator);

        int head;
        int left = 0;
        int last = array.length - 1;

        while (left < last) {
            head = left;

            // Decide the direction of the next run.
            if (comparator.compare(array[left], array[left + 1]) <= 0) {
                ++left;

                // Scanning ascending run.
                while (left < last
                        && comparator.compare(array[left], 
                                              array[left + 1]) <= 0) {
                    ++left;
                }

                heap.pushRun(head, left);
            } else {
                // Scanning strictly descending run.
                while (left < last
                        && comparator.compare(array[left], 
                                              array[left + 1]) > 0) {
                    ++left;
                }

                reverseRun(array, head, left);
                heap.pushRun(head, left);
            }

            ++left;
        }

        // A special case: the very last element may be left without buddies
        // so make it (the only) 1-element run.
        if (left == last) {
            heap.pushRun(left, left);
        }

        // Heapify. O(N) as described in "Introduction to Algorithms."
        heap.buildHeap();
        return heap;
    }

    /**
     * This class implements the actual run heap.
     * 
     * @param <T> the array component type.
     */
    private static class RunHeap<T> {
        private int size;
        private final T[] array;
        private final int[] fromIndexArray;
        private final int[] toIndexArray;
        private final Comparator<? super T> comparator;

        RunHeap(T[] array, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
            this.array = array;
            this.fromIndexArray = new int[array.length / 2 + 1];
            this.toIndexArray = new int[array.length / 2 + 1];
            this.comparator = comparator;
        }

        /**
         * Removes and returns the minimal element.
         * 
         * @return the minimal element.
         */
        T popElement() {
            T ret = array[fromIndexArray[0]];

            if (fromIndexArray[0] == toIndexArray[0]) {
                // The topmost run is exhausted.
                int last = fromIndexArray[--size];
                fromIndexArray[0] = last;
                last = toIndexArray[size];
                toIndexArray[0] = last;
            } else {
                // Increment to the next element.
                fromIndexArray[0]++;
            }

            // Possibly sift down the top element in order to restore the
            // heap invariant.
            siftDown(0);
            return ret;
        }

        /**
         * Appends the run to the tail of this heap.
         * 
         * @param fromIndex the starting inclusive index of a run.
         * @param toIndex   the ending inclusive index of a run.
         */
        void pushRun(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
            int nodeIndex = size++;
            fromIndexArray[nodeIndex] = fromIndex;
            toIndexArray[nodeIndex] = toIndex;
        }

        /**
         * Heapifies the entire heap run, restoring the heap property. Runs in
         * O(N) time, where N is the amount of runs.
         */
        void buildHeap() {
            for (int i = size / 2; i >= 0; --i) {
                siftDown(i);
            }
        }

        private boolean isLessThan(int runIndex1, int runIndex2) {
            T element1 = array[fromIndexArray[runIndex1]];
            T element2 = array[fromIndexArray[runIndex2]];

            int cmp = comparator.compare(element1, element2);

            if (cmp != 0) {
                return cmp < 0;
            }

            return fromIndexArray[runIndex1] < fromIndexArray[runIndex2];
        }

        private void siftDown(int index) {
            int nodeIndex = index;
            int leftChildIndex = (index << 1) + 1;
            int rightChildIndex = leftChildIndex + 1;
            int minIndex = index;

            for (;;) {
                if (leftChildIndex < size 
                        && isLessThan(leftChildIndex, nodeIndex)) {
                    minIndex = leftChildIndex;
                }

                if (rightChildIndex < size
                        && isLessThan(rightChildIndex, minIndex)) {
                    minIndex = rightChildIndex;
                }

                if (minIndex == nodeIndex) {
                    return;
                }

                int tmp = fromIndexArray[minIndex];
                fromIndexArray[minIndex] = fromIndexArray[nodeIndex];
                fromIndexArray[nodeIndex] = tmp;

                tmp = toIndexArray[minIndex];
                toIndexArray[minIndex] = toIndexArray[nodeIndex];
                toIndexArray[nodeIndex] = tmp;

                nodeIndex = minIndex;
                leftChildIndex = (nodeIndex << 1) + 1;
                rightChildIndex = leftChildIndex + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    private static <T> void reverseRun(T[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        for (; fromIndex < toIndex; ++fromIndex, --toIndex) {
            T tmp = array[fromIndex];
            array[fromIndex] = array[toIndex];
            array[toIndex] = tmp;
        }
    }

    private static void rangeCheck(int arrayLength, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        if (fromIndex > toIndex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "fromIndex(" + fromIndex + ") > toIndex(" + toIndex + ")");
        }

        if (fromIndex < 0) {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    "'fromIndex' is negative: " + fromIndex);
        }

        if (toIndex > arrayLength) {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    "'toIndex' is too large: " + toIndex + ", array length: " +
                    arrayLength);
        }
    }

    private static final class NaturalOrder implements Comparator<Object> {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public int compare(Object first, Object second) {
            return ((Comparable<Object>) first).compareTo(second);
        }

        private static final NaturalOrder INSTANCE = new NaturalOrder();
    }
}
```

**Demo.java:**

```
package net.coderodde.util.sorting;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import static net.coderodde.util.sorting.HeapSelectionSort.sort;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        demo();
    }

    private static Integer[] createRandomIntegerArray(int size, Random random) {
        Integer[] ret = new Integer[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            ret[i] = random.nextInt(size / 2);
        }

        return ret;
    }

    private static Integer[] createPresortedArray(int size, 
                                                  int runs, 
                                                  Random random) {
        Integer[] ret = createRandomIntegerArray(size, random);
        int runLength = size / runs;

        for (int i = 0; i < runs; ++i) {
            Arrays.sort(ret, runLength * i, 
                        Math.min(size, runLength * (i + 1)));
        }

        return ret;
    }

    private static boolean isSorted(Integer[] array, 
                                    int fromIndex, 
                                    int toIndex) {
        for (int i = fromIndex; i < toIndex - 1; ++i) {
            if (array[i].compareTo(array[i + 1]) > 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static boolean isSorted(Integer[] array) {
        return isSorted(array, 0, array.length);
    }

    private static <T> boolean arraysEqual(T[] array1, T[] array2) {
        if (array1.length != array2.length) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; ++i) {
            if (array1[i] != array2[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }    

    private static void demo() {
        long arraysSortTotal = 0L;
        long heapSelectionSortTotal = 0L;
        long seed = 3706213852107L; System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println("Seed: " + seed);
        System.out.println("-------------------");

        for (int op = 0; op < 10; ++op) {
            Random random = new Random(System.nanoTime());

            Integer[] array1 = createRandomIntegerArray(100000, random);
            Integer[] array2 = array1.clone();

            long ta = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Arrays.sort(array1);
            long tb = System.currentTimeMillis();

            System.out.println("Random array:");
            System.out.println("Arrays.sort in " + (tb - ta) + " ms, sorted: " +
                               isSorted(array1));
            arraysSortTotal += tb - ta;

            ta = System.currentTimeMillis();
            sort(array2);
            tb = System.currentTimeMillis();

            heapSelectionSortTotal += tb - ta;

            System.out.println("Heap insertion sort in " + (tb - ta) + " ms, " +
                               "sorted: " + isSorted(array2));
            System.out.println("Arrays same: " + arraysEqual(array1, array2));

            for (int i = 0; i < 80; ++i) {
                System.out.print("-");
            }

            System.out.println();

            array1 = createPresortedArray(150000, 100, random);
            array2 = array1.clone();

            ta = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Arrays.sort(array1);
            tb = System.currentTimeMillis();

            System.out.println("Presorted array:");
            System.out.println("Arrays.sort in " + (tb - ta) + " ms, sorted: " +
                               isSorted(array1));
            arraysSortTotal += tb - ta;

            ta = System.currentTimeMillis();
            sort(array2);
            tb = System.currentTimeMillis();

            heapSelectionSortTotal += tb - ta;

            System.out.println("Heap insertion sort in " + (tb - ta) + " ms, " +
                               "sorted: " + isSorted(array2));
            System.out.println("Arrays same: " + arraysEqual(array1, array2));

            for (int i = 0; i < 80; ++i) {
                System.out.print("-");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("Total of Arrays.sort: " + arraysSortTotal + " ms.");
        System.out.println("Total of heap insertion sort: " + 
                           heapSelectionSortTotal + " ms.");
    }
}
```

#### Digits I got:

> ```
>  Seed: 3706213852107
>  -------------------
>  Random array:
>  Arrays.sort in 222 ms, sorted: true
>  Heap insertion sort in 148 ms, sorted: true
>  Arrays identical: true
>  -------------------
>  Presorted array:
>  Arrays.sort in 183 ms, sorted: true
>  Heap insertion sort in 91 ms, sorted: true
>  Arrays identical: true
>  -------------------
>  Random array:
>  Arrays.sort in 33 ms, sorted: true
>  Heap insertion sort in 109 ms, sorted: true
>  Arrays identical: true
>  -------------------
>  Presorted array:
>  Arrays.sort in 30 ms, sorted: true
>  Heap insertion sort in 57 ms, sorted: true
>  Arrays identical: true
>  -------------------
>  Random array:
>  Arrays.sort in 44 ms, sorted: true
>  Heap insertion sort in 108 ms, sorted: true
>  Arrays identical: true
>  ------------------
>  Presorted array:
>  Arrays.sort in 46 ms, sorted: true
>  Heap insertion sort in 39 ms, sorted: true
>  Arrays identical: true
>  -------------------
>  Random array:
>  Arrays.sort in 53 ms, sorted: true
>  Heap insertion sort in 95 ms, sorted: true
>  Arrays identical: true
>  -------------------
>  Presorted array:
>  Arrays.sort in 29 ms, sorted: true
>  Heap insertion sort in 73 ms, sorted: true
>  Arrays identical: true
>  -------------------
>  Random array:
>  Arrays.sort in 33 ms, sorted: true
>  Heap insertion sort in 111 ms, sorted: true
>  Arrays identical: true
>  -------------------
>  Presorted array:
>  Arrays.sort in 29 ms, sorted: true
>  Heap insertion sort in 58 ms, sorted: true
>  Arrays identical: true
>  -------------------
>  Random array:
>  Arrays.sort in 42 ms, sorted: true
>  Heap insertion sort in 68 ms, sorted: true
>  Arrays identical: true
>  -------------------
>  Presorted array:
>  Arrays.sort in 31 ms, sorted: true
>  Heap insertion sort in 35 ms, sorted: true
>  Arrays identical: true
>  -------------------
>  Random array:
>  Arrays.sort in 35 ms, sorted: true
>  Heap insertion sort in 70 ms, sorted: true
>  Arrays identical: true
>  -------------------
>  Presorted array:
>  Arrays.sort in 34 ms, sorted: true
>  Heap insertion sort in 36 ms, sorted: true
>  Arrays identical: true
>  -------------------
>  Random array:
>  Arrays.sort in 32 ms, sorted: true
>  Heap insertion sort in 71 ms, sorted: true
>  Arrays identical: true
>  -------------------
>  Presorted array:
>  Arrays.sort in 30 ms, sorted: true
>  Heap insertion sort in 38 ms, sorted: true
>  Arrays identical: true
>  -------------------
>  Random array:
>  Arrays.sort in 35 ms, sorted: true
>  Heap insertion sort in 114 ms, sorted: true
>  Arrays identical: true
>  -------------------
>  Presorted array:
>  Arrays.sort in 29 ms, sorted: true
>  Heap insertion sort in 39 ms, sorted: true
>  Arrays identical: true
>  -------------------
>  Random array:
>  Arrays.sort in 32 ms, sorted: true
>  Heap insertion sort in 81 ms, sorted: true
>  Arrays identical: true
>  -------------------
>  Presorted array:
>  Arrays.sort in 35 ms, sorted: true
>  Heap insertion sort in 42 ms, sorted: true
>  Arrays identical: true
>  -------------------
>  Total of Arrays.sort: 1037 ms.
>  Total of heap insertion sort: 1483 ms.
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid @maaartinus is right about the odds to improve on the state of the art in sorting in his comment to his [answer to the initial iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/98008/93149).

With runs at most half as numerous as elements, the heap stays a bit smaller. The number of operations doesn't decrease as much, as runs need to be re-sifted.
If you declare the "non-`Comparator`-sorts" using `<T extends Comparable<T>>`, you can use `Comparator.naturalOrder()` (rendering class `NaturalOrder` dispensable) - you're casting, anyway.

I tried to reduce code multiplication in `createRunHeap`, but was not entirely successful:

```
for ( ; left < last ; left++) {
    final int head = left;
// Decide the direction of the next run.
    final boolean strictlyDecreasing =
        comparator.compare(array[left++], array[left]) < 0;
    while (left < last
           && strictlyDecreasing
              == comparator.compare(array[left++], array[left]) < 0) {
    }
// reversing strictly decreasing runs, only
//  keeps forming runs stable while increasing run count
//  by two for every run of "equal" elements
//  wedged between two strictly decreasing runs
    if (strictlyDecreasing) {
        reverseRun(array, head, left);
    }
    heap.pushRun(head, left);
}
```

But, then:

```
/** Detects changes in parameter value to the one used
 * in the constructor or first invocation, respectively */
static class ChangeDetector {
    boolean set;
    Object previous;
/** Will detect changes
 *   from the parameter of the first invocation */
    ChangeDetector(){}
/** Will detect changes from {@code initial} */
    ChangeDetector(Object initial) {
        previous = initial;
        set = true;
    }
/** @return {@code thisTime}
 *          equals parameter in constructor/first invocation */
    boolean same(Object thisTime) {
        if (!set) {
            previous = thisTime;
            return set = true;
        }
        return previous == thisTime
            || previous != null && previous.equals(thisTime);
    }
}
…
    for ( ; left < last ; left++) {
        final int head = left;
    // Decide the direction of the next run.
        ChangeDetector stays = new ChangeDetector();
        while (left < last
               && stays.same(comparator.compare(
                   array[left++], array[left]) < 0)) {
        }
        if (stays.same(Boolean.TRUE)) {
            reverseRun(array, head, left);
        }
        heap.pushRun(head, left);
    }
```